# How to create a DHCP server at home

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my server I have at home (just an old computer)

I installed `MAAS` and I have a few netbook images I'm trying to boot, I have created a `node` in `maas`, but when I boot my laptop with netboot it cannot find the netbook image.

I guarantee it is because I'm just using the default DHCP server that comes with my router, my problem is that this router is an all-in-one Modem/Router. It is able to go into bridging mode but I'm not sure where to go from there, would I put it in Bridged mode and then just plug my server into the WAN port? I've been googling and all over IRC but cannot find very good documentation to point me in the right direction.

It is a Telus Actiontec V1000H. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to bridge.  That will only mean that you'll have to configure NAT on your server, run it as a WiFi Access Point, be 100% certain your firewall is secure etc. It'll also need to be on whenever someone is using your Internet connection and as it will use more power than a small VDSL/modem/router then you'll end up with a larger electricity bill/carbon footprint.

If you're certain that your router's DHCP server is the issue, then simply switch the DHCP server off (page 46 of the manual?).

`maas` has a built-in DHCP server which you can use, or install your own. `dnsmasq` is a simple one which will probably suffice and can also substitute for your router's DNS server too if you so wish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My ISP has their own sort of firmware on their routers which disables me from accessing options like disabling DHCP. Is there a way to work around this without disabling DHCP on my router. I'm unsure how to run my server as a WiFi AP either.

Comment: That's not nice of them ;-) Does [this article](http://keithbalomben.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/telus-actiontec-v1000h-hacks-and-information/) help? It shows how to access hidden pages on the router.  It does warn though that it may not work with non-standard firmware.  Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, I've googled probably anything you could find yourself, nothing works as of the latest firmware. Unable to downgrade or anything..

Comment: As you can't disable DHCP then you're quite limited in what you can do.  You could consider replacing the router with a friendlier one. As per my answer, your should be able to have your server act as an access point (depending on your WiFi apapter) for a new (isolated from the router's DHCP server) subnet but it will involve quite a bit of configuration on your part.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to run this routes in bridge mode(Telus dislike it) this [article](http://npopson.com/archives/2202) describe how to do it.